# Plesk passenger django watch manage.py logs

Tags: django, plesk

I am using django over Plesk. For this, it is necessary to install passengers in plesk.
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002701209-How-to-allow-installing-and-install-Django-applications-

When I write python manage.py runserver while working on localhost, I can watch all manage.py logs instantly.

But since I am not running this command while working on this plesk passenger, I cannot see any log record.

How can I watch manage.py log records instantly?

im using centos7 - plesk onyx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution

just add settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
'applogfile': {
    'level':'WARNING',
    'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
    'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logfile.log'),
    'maxBytes': 1024*1024*15, # 15MB
    'backupCount': 10,
    },
}
```